# Why am I losing my characters from my html string when trying to add html dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that I am trying to dynamically add some links to. The links are getting added to the page fine, but the '[' and ']' at either end of the line are getting dropped. The code from my .js file is:

```
var html = "[ <a href='#'>Change</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href='#'>Remove </a> ]";
$(html).appendTo("#id123");
```

The result I want is:

```
[ <a href='#'>Change</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href='#'>Remove</a> ]
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
<a href='#'>Change</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href='#'>Remove</a>
```

If I wrap the line in a `<span>` tag like so:

```
var html = "<span>[ <a href='#'>Change</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href='#'>Remove </a> ]</span>";
$(html).appendTo("#id123");
```

it renders as expected. I set a breakpoint on the code and checked the html var right before the .appendTo and it contains the '[' and ']'.

Anyone know why this is happening? Are '[' and ']' special character that need escaped and I'm just forgetting that fact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you wrap your html variable inside of "$()", it creates a jQuery object out of it. That object removes anything that's outside of a markup tag (like <a> or <span>). You can take out the"[" and put "TESTING THIS" in it's place and you'll see it still won't show up.

So that's why you're losing it in your output.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what the problem was. Sad thing is, I knew that too. I'll blame my mental lapse on the fact that its Friday afternoon of a long week.

Answer (score 2):

No, those are just not valid XHTML. If you put the '[' and ']' in their own spans, like so:

```
 "<span>[&nbsp;</span><a href='#'>Change</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href='#'>Remove </a></span>&nbsp;]</span>"
```

You would also get your expected text. jQuery will parse and create valid HTML, and the brackets aren't contained in an element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happens. It seems like something internal to the `appendTo()` I tried it with `append()` and it worked out fine. So you could write `$("#id123").append(html)`